# is there a way to quickly delete or empty an array of json objects?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I've got a json array like this

```
this.nodes = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parent": null,
    "name": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parent": 1,
        "name": "ok it works",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "parent": 1,
        "name": "ok it works",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent": null,
    "name": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "parent": 3,
        "name": "ok it works",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "parent": 3,
        "name": "",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what is the fastest way to empty the array, I've tried

```
this.nodes = []
```

but got this error after running that line

```
vendor.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:8 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (vendor.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:641)
    at MapSubscriber.project (app.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:171)
    at MapSubscriber._next (vendor.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:676)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (vendor.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:420)
    at XMLHttpRequest.a (vendor.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:655)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:36)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:36)
    at Zone.runTask (polyfills.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js:36)
```

I've got a deeply nested array of json objects, so is there a quick way to delete it all, reset it to an empty array without having to recursivly go through the whole tree and delete each child first before deleting the parent all the way up to the main parent?

Btw I am running this inside Angularjs and I render a set of nested components based on the array I showed you above.

Comment: `this.nodes = []` will set `this.nodes` to an empty array -  not sure why you have a JSON.parse error, unless you're trying to `JSON.parse(this.nodes)` after setting it to an empty array ... JSON is a string ... so, there's actually no JSON in your question at all

Comment: Look at line 8 of `vendor.f0f5c3b4d9bf656cfa2b.js` to see the actual code that throws the error

Answer (score 0):

Store this into a variable, hence:

```
var vm = this;
vm.nodes = [.....];
vm.nodes = [];
```